# Is anything wrong in the source i written

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I write a code to print the value of a textbox to another textbox but i am unable to achieve this can any one tell what's wrong or can any give me equivalent `JavaScript` to achieve this

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jQuery/1.2.6/jQuery.min.js"> 
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
$('#TextBox1').keyup(function(){
$('#TextBox2').val(this.value);
});
        </script>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I am not sure what `this` is referencing to there. I would check that.

Comment: When you "View source" on your page, what do the `<textarea>` "id" values look like?  Are you sure that ASP isn't giving them qualified names or something?

Comment: Nothing seems to  work for me i am getting `object excepted` can i have a javascript please

Comment: @Cobra_Fast you can be completely sure that `this` will refer to the "TextBox1" element in the event handler, because jQuery works that way.

Comment: @Dorababu: asp:TextBox produces an <input type='text'> field?

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti whether it's a "text" input or a `<textarea>` should not matter here; both have "value" attributes.

Comment: @pointy Yes i was just curious because i don't know asp!

Comment: @Dorababu: have you tried writing "debugger;"  inside the keyup() function?

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti : Can you tell where exactly should i write that one

Comment: `$('#TextBox1').keyup(function(){
debugger; $('#TextBox2').val(this.value);
});` When you do this, when you press a key in the first area you should see the debug window. If you don't see the debug window the event is not attached.  If you use Firefox you can use firebug to debug javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot but it seems `jquery` did not work so i got the required by the following

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function sync()
{
  var n1 = document.getElementById('TextBox1');
  var n2 = document.getElementById('TextBox2');
  n2.value = n1.value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two potential problems.  One, as identified by @Neal and @Nicola, is that you need to wrap anything that references a DOM element inside of

```
$(document).ready(funcution(){ 
  // here
});

// or, this way, both are equivalent
$(function(){

});
```

Secondly, the ID assigned to your text boxes is most likely NOT TextBox1 and TextBox2. This is because ASP.NET generates unique ID's for the client side.  They will most likely look something like:

```
ctl00_TextBox1
```

or something similar.  Check the generated HTML source of your page to confirm.  Also, I've found the JavaScript console of FireFox's Firebug plugin or Chromes developer tools to be very useful for identifying if my jQuery selector is actually returning anything.  Just pop open the console in one of those browsers, and execute:

```
$('#TextBox1');
```

If you selector works, you'll get an array with 1 element in it.  If it isn't finding anything, it'll just return an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work. You need the     `$(document).ready(function(){});` wrapper so that the handler is attached after the dom is ready. I edited with the inclusion script from CDN

```
<script src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js”></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#TextBox1').keyup(function(){
         $('#TextBox2').val($(this).val());
        });
    };
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap in ready (for your js to execute when the DOM is ready):

```
$(function(){

   $('#TextBox1').keyup(function(){
       $('#TextBox2').val(this.value);
   });

});
```

Comment: +1 That's the issue (along with the corrected ID). I didn't even notice that.

Comment: @patrick dw as long as the elements are in the DOM when the script runs, it should work fine.

Comment: In the code as posted they are, @Neal - of course, if the code as posted is not the actual code, then we really have no idea what's going on :-)

Comment: @Pointy: You're right. I'm very confused today. The elements are certainly in the DOM before the script. I was messing with Erlang yesterday. I think it fried my brain!

Comment: @pointy, true, true, but i always make it a habit to wrap my code just incase

Comment: @Neal well yes, I wouldn't write the code that way, but in this case I doubt it's the problem. My money is on this being an ASP "client ID" issue, though I'm not an ASP programmer so I don't know for sure. @patrick dw Erlang is a blast - have fun!

Comment: @All : I don't have any JavaScript for this in a separate file or folder i just write as i posted will this work i tried all the posted posts here but nothing works for me

Answer (score -1):

Since text boxes place their content between `<textarea>` tags rather than in a `value` attribute, you'll likely have better luck using `$(this).text()` rather than `this.value`:

```
$('#TextBox1').keyup(function() {
    $('#TextBox2').text($(this).text());
});
```

Also, `#TextBox12` != `#TextBox2`.

Comment: No, for a `<textarea>` you should use the `value` property because it updates with the user's input.

Comment: I've never ever heard of inputs behaving like textareas. Never.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: So you're saying the `.value` property is not correct?

Comment: @patrick dw No, I was saying that "I've never ever heard of inputs behaving like textareas." ...

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: Yes, I read your comment. Because you were so emphatic, it seemed that you were making some point. I'm just not sure what it is.

Comment: @patrick dw If I had a more sophisticated point, I would have stated it. For sure.

Comment: @Luke: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/k8u38/). Just edit the textarea from its original value, then blur it. You'll see that `.text()` doesn't give you the updated value (in Chrome anyway).